# Is it possible to apply material design to react native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I see apps in android that follow material design themes, so whenever a user changes the wallpaper of their phone, the colors also vary which changes the app's colors too.

Just like Google apps, they follow the system accent colors, primary colors, text colors, etc.

For example:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SQvO.png) :
this app follows system colors i.e. brown

I want to know how to do this stuff in react native. Is there any way to get the list of the system colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this one?
https://www.react-native-material.com/

Has a lot of components that could be customised.

Comment: Yes, but this is a typical material UI thing, I don't know if it can change colors based on the system theme or not. I wanted something which can fetch the system color palette. Anyways I'll give it a go

Comment: ah ok, got it...I haven't tried that before. Maybe you can combine PlatformColor (https://reactnative.dev/docs/platformcolor), and useColorScheme (https://reactnative.dev/docs/usecolorscheme), and play with that

Answer (score 0):

I recommend react native paper, it has a lot of components and nice customization
https://reactnativepaper.com/

It has support for custom material you dark and light theme. It does not have a built in automatic switch between light and dark, but you can use react native Appearance to get device theme yourself

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).